# How to implement a share button in Flutter app?

Tags: facebook, share, flutter

In my app, I have a button and I need it to share Facebook when this button is clicked?

Comment: You want to share on Facebook? or Just want share ?

Comment: on facebook @dhuma1981

Answer (score 46):

Check out flutter share plugin

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

```
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');
```

Then users can choose to use facebook or any other service that supports share interface

Comment: Do you have example of how to post to fb timeline?

Comment: you need to have installed facebook on your phone, than facebook will be in the options to choose from once you click share

Comment: What about a plugin that supports flutter web?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this package:
https://pub.dev/packages/wc_flutter_share

This package supports sharing image + text both.

You can use this like:

```
await WcFlutterShare.share(  
    sharePopupTitle: 'share',  
    subject: 'This is subject',  
    text: 'This is text',  
    fileName: 'share.png',  
    mimeType: 'image/png',  
    bytesOfFile: bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
```

***Note:*** On facebook you can't share image and text at the same time. You can either share text or image.

Comment: This package is no longer supported.

Answer (score 5):

This is for us Flutter noobs, a more complete solution.

1. Add this at the top of your .dart file:

   ```
   import 'package:share/share.dart';
   ```
2. Run this command in your Terminal:

   ```
   flutter pub add share
   ```
3. Add the share code into the button code in onPressed:

   ```
   onPressed: () {
               Share.share('check out my website https://example.com', subject: 'Look what I made!');
   }),
   ```

More information about the share package can be found on the link below:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/share

Comment: This package is no longer supported.
This plugin has been replaced by the Flutter Community Plus Plugins version, share_plus

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

Answer (score 4):

try this: https://github.com/d-silveira/flutter-share.git

if you want to share something other than text.

it allows sharing text/image/file with a simple named constructor instantiation `Share.image(path: <PATH>, title: <TITLE>)` and then call `share()` on it

just follow the instructions for further details on the README or see a working example in the example project folder.

It is fully functional for Android, the IOS part is currently being developed to match the Android part.

Comment: Does it now support ios? Do you have example of how to post to fb timeline?

Answer (score 1):

**share_plus 3.0.4**: https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus
A Flutter plugin to share content from your Flutter app via the platform's share dialog.

Run this command with Flutter:

```
$ flutter pub add share_plus
```

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit flutter pub get):

```yaml
dependencies:
  share_plus: ^3.0.4
```

- Import the library

```dart
    import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
```

- Then invoke the static share method anywhere in your Dart code.

```dart
Share.share('hey! check out this new app https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3ADivTag&c=apps');
```

- The share method also takes an optional subject that will be used when sharing to email.

```dart
Share.share('hey! check out this new app https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3ADivTag&c=apps', subject: 'DivTag Apps Link');
```

[Platform Support](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus#platform-support) :
Android | iOS | MacOS | Web | Linux | Windows

#### Note

> **share 2.0.4** : https://pub.dev/packages/share This plugin has been replaced by the Flutter Community Plus Plugins version, to share_plus. No further updates are planned to this plugin, and they are encourage all users to migrate to the Plus version.

Comment: Does anyone know why this plugin does not share text on facebook and fb msger?!

Comment: Don't know exactly, but the reason may be privacy policy, limitations, and security at different platforms.

Comment: Due to restrictions set up by Facebook this plugin isn't capable of sharing data reliably to Facebook related apps on Android and iOS. This includes eg. sharing text to the Facebook Messenger. If you require this functionality please check the native Facebook Sharing SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) or search for other Flutter plugins implementing this SDK. More information can be found in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus

```
 Share.shareXFiles([XFile(file.path)], text: 'filename');
```