# How do I add the share feature to an icon in flutter [on button click share app in social media ]

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I want a feature to share my app on social media.
2. The share icon will be placed inside the app bar. When the user clicks on the share icon, social media options will be displayed to the user.
3. I know about **SHARE PACKAGE** but I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/share

Comment: I know about this package.. But how to set up it..PLease guide me.. I want to display share option whenever  users  click on the share icon

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a share button in Flutter app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573933/how-to-implement-a-share-button-in-flutter-app)

Comment: this is a duplicate question.. I know this but previous question answers are not explained well.. This question asked by me solved my  problem..

Answer (score 9):

after installing the package you need to import it to your dart file:

```
import 'package:share/share.dart';
```

you can create an icon button like this:

```
IconButton(icon:Icon(Icons.share),
onPressed:(){
Share.share('check out my website https://example.com');}
),
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement on click method in Icons instead of iconbutton?

Comment: Its possible to put an icon inside an InkWell Widget and give the inkwell widget onTap:
InkWell(onTap: (){},
child:Icon(Icons.share))