# how to send a photo using image picker to my hp color printer?

Tags: android, flutter, printing, imagepicker

I send some images to firebase storage, then another fetches the images and need to print it on a photo paper. what flutter API can I use.

I have managed to use call the native api using methodchannel and it seems to in redirecting to print service. But it only goes to the print service ,where i have to click print and does not initiate printing directly.

Please add your suggestions on how to directly initiate the printing.

Comment: I think you need to share the file with the printer (via Bluetooth), please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573933/how-to-implement-a-share-button-in-flutter-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.example.print1
import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.BatteryManager
import android.os.Build.VERSION
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.R
import androidx.print.PrintHelper
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import android.R.drawable
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery"
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
            // Note: this method is invoked on the main thread.
                call, result ->
            if (call.method == "Printphoto") {
                doPhotoPrint()

            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun doPhotoPrint() {
        println("heloo the yout");
        activity.also { context ->
            PrintHelper(context).apply {
                scaleMode = PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT
            }.also { printHelper ->
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.alert_dark_frame)
                printHelper.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap)
            }
        }

    }
}


static const platform = const MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/battery');
      String _printstatus =       'printing photo';
      Future<void> Printphotocall() async {
        String batteryLevel;
        try {
          final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('doPhotoPrint');
          _printstatus = 'Battery level at $result % .';
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          _printstatus = "Failed to print: '${e.message}'.";
        }
        setState(() {
          _printstatus = batteryLevel;
        });
      }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).